# Service continues to act as shared when shared is set to false

Tags: 9, caching, symfony-services

According to Symfony docs, doing `shared: false` on a service should mean that each time you call a service, you get a new instance. However, this doesn't seem to work for me. I am using Drupal 9 which runs on Symfony 4.4.

My services.yml :

```
services:
  my_module.arbitrary_data:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Services\ArbitraryData
    arguments: ['@another_module.contextual_uid']
    shared: false
```

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/shared.html

I've also tried the deprecated `scope: prototype` and `scope: request` methods to no avail. If I load a page, my services outputs unchanged data from the last time the page was loaded until I clear cache.

Regardless of doing this, the services fail to run after the first page load after clearing cache and just proceed to output unchanged data every time. This feels like "unwanted caching".

Edit 11/15 3:47PM
The render array from the plugin using the service, as requested:

```
$service = \Drupal::service('my_module.arbitrary_data');
$data = $service->get('acr');
$data = array_shift($data);

return [
  '#markup' => $data['value'],
];
```

Comment: I agree that according to https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file this is supposed to be supported. I don't, however, understand the symptoms you described in the way you described them.

Comment: Where are you invoking the service? Inside a hook which is cached maybe? What does the cache look like on the render array which is outputting the data?

Comment: Setting a service to not shared only has an effect on the service properties in memory, not the Drupal cache data stored in the database.

Comment: @Clive It's being used in a controller that is not being cached, in fact the route that calls the controller is set to no_cache.

Comment: @cilefen Imagine you have a custom service which returns the current time. On the first request, the service returns the time. On the second request, the same time as the first request is returned. I have a feeling that there is a cache context that needs to be changed somewhere, I just don't know where or what.

Comment: Could you post a copy of the render array being returned from the controller in the question (or whatever other method you're using to return the content). Your problem isn't related to the `shared` parameter by the way, as 4uk4 mentioned

Comment: @Clive I have added it to the original post for readability. The controller is part of a plugin, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user @Clive 's questioning, it led me to assess this issue as a Plugin problem rather than a Service problem. Since the service is being used in a plugin, and the plugin was being cached (by default), my output was not changing.

Implementing cache max-age into the plugin's render array fixed this issue.

```
return [
  '#markup' => $data['value'],
  '#cache' => [
    'max-age' => 0,
  ],
];
```